# Create an Array with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, append

I have two functions. The first function takes the users input in a text box and appends it to a div and then displays it in the html. The second will make a change in the word from the user and change the background and color of the word, this way the word changes the color and the background for the word. The first function works fine, the second function is where I am having issues. I haven't created an array with jQuery before so I am guessing there is something wrong with my syntax because my code is running as if there was no second function. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Here are the functions

```
function listWordsUsed(wordUsed) {
    var userTrials = $('#userGuesses');
    var divisor = $("<div>" + wordUsed + "</div>");
    divisor.hide().appendTo(userTrials).fadeIn(7000);
    return;
} //End of function listWordsUsed(wordUsed) 

function addStyleToAnswers(wordUsed) {
    listWordsUsed(wordUsed);
    theGuess = $("div").toArray();
        for (i=0; i< theGuess.length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                $("#userGuesses").addClass("oddGuess");
            } //if (i % 2 = 0)
            else
            {
                $("#userGuesses").addClass("evenGuess");
            } //else
        } //for (i=0; i< wordUsed.length; i++)
} //function addStyleToAnswers(wordUsed)
```

Here is the CSS file for the functions

```
.oddGuesses {
    color: orange;
    background-color: blue;
}

.evenGuesses {
    color: blue;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: since code doesn't really make a lot of sense, what are your expectations?

Comment: Here is what I want. I will run the `addStyleToAnswers(wordUsed)` function inside the `addStyleToAnswers(wordUsed)` function. For the first word entered by the guest the background will be changed to blue and the text will be orange, for the second word the background will be orange and the text will be blue and so on, and then the text will be printed in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over a jquery object you can use `.each()` http://api.jquery.com/each/
Like:

```
function addAnswer (wordUsed) {
  var userTrials = $('#userGuesses');
  var divisor = $('<div class="word">' + wordUsed + '</div>');
  divisor.hide().appendTo(userTrials).fadeIn(7000);
  return;
}

function addStyleToAnswers(wordUsed) {
  $('.word').each(function(index){
    if (index%2 === 0) {
      $(this).addClass('odd')
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('even')
    }
  });
}

addAnswer();
addStyleToAnswers();
```

But when you just want to style even or odd elements you can do this in css with
`div:nth-child(odd)` and `div:nth-child(even)` at least when you dont care about IE8

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the nth-child for CSS. That did the trick. I found this page helpful [link](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)